# Setting up a function in a class that will read in csv data in a way that it can be referenced in future functions

Tags: python, pandas, csv, class, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to determine the best way to define a function within a class that reads a specific .csv file if a criterion is met. Then, the function returns the data in the file. But I need it to return the data in a way that allows me to call on those data again in a future function in the class.

Some background: The data I'm reading in are time-stamped temperatures. The columns in each .csv file are `'day', 'hour', 'temp_1', 'temp_2', 'temp_3', 'temp_4'` Then, there are rows of numeric data for each hour of the year, so around 9,000 rows.

I need to define a function that reads in the data from a csv file, then allows me to recall the temp data, and corresponding day and hour in future functions.

```
### Here I define the class. I just included a shortened version of this. 
### The class has more arguments than this. I just included the relevant parameter which is 'group'

class Individual():
    def __init__(self,group):
        self.group = group
        
### This is the function, or set of functions, that I'm trying to get running


    def return_temp1(self, day, hour):
        if self.group =='a':
            micro_df = pd.read_csv('ex1.csv')
        elif self.group =='b':
            micro_df = pd.read_csv('ex2.csv')
        return micro_df.temp1,day,hour
        
    def return_temp2(self, day, hour):
        if self.group =='a':
            micro_df = pd.read_csv('ex1.csv')
        elif self.group =='b':
            micro_df = pd.read_csv('ex2.csv')
        return micro_df.temp2,day,hour
   
     def return_temp3(self, day, hour):
        if self.group =='a':
            micro_df = pd.read_csv('ex1.csv')
        elif self.group =='b':
            micro_df = pd.read_csv('ex2.csv')
        return micro_df.temp3,day,hour
   
    
     def return_temp4(self, day, hour):
        if self.group =='a':
            micro_df = pd.read_csv('ex1.csv')
        elif self.group =='b':
            micro_df = pd.read_csv('ex2.csv')
        return micro_df.temp4,day,hour
   
### Then, later I need to define more functions where I'm able to call 
# on the temperatures pulled from the csv files in the above functions. 
# I've included one of those functions below as an example.


    def calculate_longwave_radiation(self, temp1): 
        return 53.1*10**-14*(temp1 +273.15)**6.
```

I'm fairly new to Python, and very new to using classes. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated! I know something with the way I've set up the `return` lines is causing the issue (or at least part of it)... but I can't figure out how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Put it on `self`. ie: `self.micro_df_a = pd.read_csv('ex1.csv')`. Then you can reference the dataframe from anywhere in your code with `self.micro_df_a`

Comment: I don't understand the question (honestly). Is the issue over things like `return micro_df.temp4,day,hour` _et al._?

Comment: Hi @That1Guy, thank you for the help. I'm trying to understand your solution. Is it similar to what the answer below is saying? How would ```self.micro_df_a``` return a specific column of data in the csv?

Comment: @roganjosh yes, I think the problem is that the function is not returning the correct thing, or correctly reading in the csv file in a way that I can reference those data in future functions... running the code as I've included above gives me a ```micro_df is not defined``` error message. So something about it isn't working.

Comment: If anyone who responded is able to clarify their answers/suggestions, that would be really helpful. I'm new to python and the information you guys kindly took the time to give has not brought me any closer to solving my problem. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I'll use a language here which may not be best pythonic language, but as you're new in python, it may guide you in the process.

The pd, or pandas dataframe you are using in your code, are like excel sheets, or a table.

So, what you can do is to create a def called load_data() in your class, and then you load ex1.csv and ex2.csv in df_ex1 and df_ex2 respectively. You can also concatenate the data in a single df if they have the same format. Those dfs should be attributes of the class. Like:

```
class Individual():
    def __init__(self,group):
        self.group = group
        df_ex1 = pd.DataFrame
```

Once you do the above you can create all defs you need and reference the dataframes to extract data from them. Like

```
    def return_temp1(self, day, hour):
        if self.group =='a':
            micro_df = df_ex1[['day', 'hour']].loc[df_ex1['day'] == day])
        return micro_df
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Fabricio, but I don't quite follow you here. You're saying that all of the groups (I'll have ~40 of them) should be listed as attributes when I'm setting up the class, right? Also, in your ```def return_temp1``` function I don't think it would return the temp value as it is written. Could you clarify the 3rd line of code in that function please?

Comment: Fabricio- another quick question, to make the dfs attributes of the class, I would still have to have ```self.``` prior to the attribute, right? I don't understand how you've written it because it seems like the df and the group are separate attributes of the class. Any more help would be really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: It seems all your ~40 groups have the same format ('day', 'hour', 'temp_1', 'temp_2', 'temp_3', 'temp_4'). If this is true you can create a loop and add all data to the same df. You can also add a column in the df with the file name.

And yes, you must use self.df_ex1 = pd.DataFrame

Comment: Ok. Thank you. This method sounds a little complicated to me. If I wanted to do this similarly to the attempt I describe in my question, and have 4 different functions for temp1, temp2, temp3, temp4, and then I just specify the different paths for the different groups as I've done... how could I modify the return line of code to get the temp data? Are you aware of any way to do that? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: return micro_df[['temp1','day','hour']]